# Is there any way using generic sql to insert a string longer than 4000 chars into a CLOB

Tags: sql, oracle, clob, ora-01704

Is there any way using generic sql to insert a string longer than 4000 chars into a CLOB

New Column Added:

```
ALTER TABLE MESSAGES ADD (MESSAGE_CLOB CLOB);

INSERT INTO TF_STP_MESSAGES
           (ID,
            MESSAGE_CLOB)
    VALUES (MSG_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
            TO_CLOB ('STRING WITH 10000 CHARACHTER'));
```

Oracle returns the following message:

> PL/SQL: ORA-01704: string literal too long

I have to insert it by SQL

Please advise.

Comment: See if you can find the answer here:  https://community.oracle.com/thread/1068414 .Surprisingly seems to be the exact same question .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an anonymous block (or a procedure) to run the `insert` statement by declaring as a `CLOB` variable and using it in insert.

```
DECLARE

v_message_clob CLOB := 'STRING WITH 10000 CHARACTERS';

BEGIN 
INSERT INTO TF_STP_MESSAGES
           (ID,
            MESSAGE_CLOB)
    VALUES (MSG_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
            v_message_clob);
END;
/
```